# Is there any way to parse from boolean to integer in Common Lisp?

Tags: int, boolean, lisp, common-lisp

I'm looking for some built-in function or some operator in Common Lisp that will return '0' when the input is a false boolean expression, and '1' when it is true. An example would be:

```
(setq a 3)
(setq b (+ (bool-to-int (< 0 a)) 2)
(print "b should be 1 + 2 = 3")
```

Is there a way to do this with Common Lisp without defining a custom function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write `(if <exp> 1 0)` wherever you need to boolean expression to be mapped to `[0, 1]`. There is no builtin form to do it exactly as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a very elegant solution, but you could create a hash table, for example,

```
(setf *ht-bool-to-int* (make-hash-table))
(setf (gethash nil *ht-bool-to-int*) 0)
(setf (gethash t *ht-bool-to-int*) 1)
(defun bool-to-int (b)
     (gethash (not (not b)) *ht-bool-to-int*))
```

(edit: nested not for random expression that would evaluate to true but not directly register for the hash table)
Then you could implement your own version of "if" without using the built-in if, i.e.,

```
(defmacro my-if (condition then-clause else-clause)
  (let ((ev (gensym)))
     `(let ((,ev (vector (quote ,else-clause) (quote ,then-clause))))
          (eval (aref ,ev (bool-to-int ,condition))))))
```

after-thought: is the hash table implemented using if?